# jQuery ajax deferred done not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have an ajax call I am performing and the response is 200 OK but it is not working on the **done deferred** method. I have tried using the **success callback** in the old jQuery (this is depreciated as of 1.8) way but this is not working either. Using the **fail deferred** method works find and so does the **always deferred** method but this seems more like a hack to use than doing it the proper way and using done. What am I missing?

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: core.api_url + '/quote/' + core.quote_id + '/items',
    type: 'put',
    dataType: 'array',
    data: $.extend({}, items), // Needs to be converted to an object of objects because jQuery ajax cannot handle arrays of objects
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.message-container .ui.message.saved').addClass('hidden');
        $('.message-container .ui.message.saving').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}).done(function(response){
    $('.message-container .ui.message.saving').addClass('hidden');
    if(response.success == true){
        $('.message-container .ui.message.saved').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    if(response.success == false){
        $('.message-container .ui.message.failed').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

**Console Logs**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

Response:
{"success":true,"results":[{"id":31}]}
```

Comment: Uhm, I don't think `dataType: 'array',` is valid, you'd have to output JSON.

Comment: Is there any reason on why you dont want to use `success: function(){...}` and `error: function(){...}`

Comment: If you look at the browser console or use the debugger you will find that the callback is called normally but it causes an error...

Comment: FYI, `fail` fires on errors, `always` fires, well always, and `done` fires only if the request was successful. Your request is not successful. If you log the arguments of the `fail` handler to the console, you'll see what went wrong

Comment: The console does not return an error jon. Also, user1354678, the success and error callbacks are not recommended as of version 1.8 of jQuery. adeneo is right and the dataType array is not allowed. I have changed this to JSON and it works correctly. Thanks!

Comment: This is from the jQuery docs - Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: That is referring to the success callback of the `jqXHR`, not the `success` parameter of `$.ajax`.

Comment: Those are not the same methods! The properties of the options object named `success`, `error` etc. are not deprecated, but the **methods** with the same name are, as in `$.ajax(options).success(function() { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Like adeneo said: dataType: 'array' is invalid and probably jquery will trigger the .fail() instead of .done().

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly I did not realise that dataType array is not allowed. Changing this to json works as expected.

To all those saying to use success, complete or error. These are indeed depreciated as of jQuery 1.8. See below for a direct reference from the jQuery docs.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax